# How to make a density plot with composed functions

Tags: plotting, pure-function

I want to create a monochromatic density plot of the E-field around an optical vortex. To do this I've written

```
l = 10; p = 2; w = 1; 

ρ              := Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]; 
θ              := ArcTan[x, y];
Llp[x_]        := (x^-l E^x)/p! D[E^-x x^(l + p), {x, p}]
ulp[ρ_]        := (-1)^p (Sqrt[2] ρ/w)^ l Llp[2 ρ^2/w^2] Exp[-ρ^2/w^2]
efield[ρ_, θ_] := ulp[ρ, l, p] Cos[l θ]

DensityPlot[efield[ρ, θ, l, p], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4},  ColorFunction -> GrayLevel]
```

I cannot even define the function to be differentiated in `Llp[x]`. When I try

```
f[x] = E^-x x^(l + p)
```

I get the `"Tag Times protected"` error, which I haven't been able to figure out from documentation.

Comment: What do you mean by `When I try f[x] = E^-x x^(l + p) ...` I don't see any `f[]` in your code ...

Comment: Although I answered, I'm also voting to close the question. It's no reflection on you, as this is exactly the kind of situation that beginners often find themselves in; *Mathematica* is quite confusing at first. But, because it relates to particular code that exhibits a variety of rather specific problems, I think the question and answer probably cannot be very useful to anyone else in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have some stray definitions in your session. If you would start again, then only minor modifications are needed to your code to make it work correctly:

```
l = 10; p = 2; w = 1; 

ρ                      := Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]; 
θ                      := ArcTan[x, y];
Llp[x_]                 = (x^-l E^x)/p! D[E^-x x^(l + p), {x, p}];
ulp[ρ_, l_, p_]        := (-1)^p (Sqrt[2] ρ/w)^ l Llp[2 ρ^2/w^2] Exp[-ρ^2/w^2];
efield[ρ_, θ_, l_, p_] := ulp[ρ, l, p] Cos[l θ];

DensityPlot[
 efield[ρ, θ, l, p], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4},
 ColorFunction -> GrayLevel, MaxRecursion -> 3
]
```

> [image: Plot of the optical vortex as output from DensityPlot]

The main problem comes from the delayed definition for `Llp`. By making it an immediate definition (using `Set` instead of `SetDelayed`), we do not have the problem that `D` tries to differentiate with respect to a number, since `x` remains intact as a symbol at the time of the definition.

The other problems are that your definitions for `ulp` and `efield` do not have all of the parameters given.

Answer (score 3):

Couldn't resist using Oleksander's excellent answer and plotting it in a more snazzy way:

```
ComplexPlotR2[CCompileR2[efield[ρ, θ, l, p]], {-4.001, 4, 0.01}, {-4.001, 4, 0.01}, 0.0005]
```

which gives

[image]

using the following custom plot method:

```
hue = Compile[{{z, _Complex}}, {(1.0 Arg[-z] + π)/(2 π), 
    Exp[1 - Max[Abs[z], 1]], Min[Abs[z], 1]}, 
   CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}];
ComplexPlotR2[f_, {x0_, x1_, δx_}, {y0_, y1_, δy_}, 
   mag_] := 
  Image[hue[
     mag f[#[[All, All, 1]], #[[All, All, 2]]] &@
      Outer[List, Range[x0, x1, δx], 
       Range[y1, y0, -δy]]]\[Transpose], ColorSpace -> Hue, 
   Magnification -> 1];
CCompileR2[expr_] := 
  Compile[{{x, _Real}, {y, _Real}}, Evaluate[expr], 
   CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}];
```

Areas in red are positive, and areas in blue are negative (it also works for functions $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$. Using this color scheme for visualization (instead of `GrayLevel`) has the advantage that areas of zero field are in black, which has minimum perceptual luminance. For better (but more computationally expensive) color schemes, check out [Matteo Niccoli's blog](https://mycarta.wordpress.com/).

Comment: I am preparing to delete this question in routine maintenance but I like this plot code.  Would you consider self-answering a question of your own to keep it on the site?